# Find pair with least value of LCM in a given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I recently came across a question on a competitive programming contest. Given an array of integers, find indices of a pair of array elements with least value of LCM.

I know there's a naive double loop O(n^2) solution but as expected, it gave a time limit exception. I've heard that dynamic programming is used to optimise brute force approaches but I'm not able to get how to divide this problem into subproblems so that there's an optimal substructure.

Can I get any direction to approach this problem using DP? Or any better approach? Thanks.

Comment: pre-procees each numbers to have prime numbers decomposition might help.

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: I think in the general case (e. g. none of the numbers in the array share any prime factors), you will always end up with O(n²) because you will have to compute the product of each combination and compare their sizes.  The only possibility to improve your speed might be in the special case (admittedly a probably very common one) that the elements have a lot of prime factors in common.

Comment: @Alfe if all the numbers are coprime you could just take the 2 smallest numbers O(n)

Comment: @maraca You are right if you know that they are all coprime.  If you have this assumption, testing it is also just O(n), but I was assuming the "normal" case that some will be coprime and some won't, so you have to come up with something which can deal with _this_ case, and this (not specialized) algorithm will have O(n²) on a list of all coprime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

*(Assuming positive numbers.)*

The smallest LCM is likely to stem from the smallest elements, hence to prune trying values one could sort the array.

```
int[] v = { ... };

int minLCM = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int bestVi = -1;
int bestVj = -1;
Arrays.sort(v);
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
    int vi = v[i];
    //                                  _____________
    for (int j = i + 1; j < v.length && v[j] < minLCM; ++j) {
        int vj = v[j];
        int lcm = lcm(vi, vj);
        if (lcm < minLcm) {
            minLCM = lcm;
            bestVi = vi;
            bestVj = vj;
        }
    }
}
```

For pruning:

```
lcm(vi, vj) >= vi
lcm(vi, vj) >= vj
(lcm(vi, vj) <= vi*vj
```

This pruning can be done in the for-j loop only as `vj >= vi`.

Better pruning could be done if instead a number you had a list of (at most `²log value`)prime factors.
As factorisation costs too, one might just try for (2, 3, 5, 7) for instance.

Better looping can also achieved by replacing both nested loops so that the smallest (vi, vj) come first. Above (v0, v100) comes before (v1, v2). Loop over an increasing i+j.

```
i j
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 2
0 4
1 3
0 5
1 4
2 3
...
```

(The math for the loop counters using diagonals is a nice puzzle. **Should really be done.**)

Though still `O(n²)` this might work.

*Sometimes also the programming language matters, and one sees in those contexts often C contributions. In such a case using Ruby might be contraproductive.*